# UIWebView not loading HTML string

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using UIWebView to load my HTML string,

```
NSMutableString * str;
str = [NSMutableString new];
[str appendString:@"<html><head><title>HO</title></head><body>"];
[str appendString:content];
[str appendString:@"</body></html>"];
[webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

It works fine before, but when I update to iOS 10, it didn't load anymore.

Does anyone know why it happened?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for responding,

I've just solve my problem.

In webviewdidfinishload,

```
    webViewHeight = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight"] floatValue];
```

I changed document.height to document.body.scrollHeight.

Comment: Youre a life saver!!

Answer (score 0):

I tested and your code still work well on iOS 10.2. Please check `content` or post a sample.